# In Bigquery SQL: How to fetch previous week, specified week and next week data?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Scenario:** From bigquery, have to fetch the specified date's week data + its previous week data + its next future week data. Week starts is Wednesday.

**Tried Query:**

```
Select * from table
and extract(week(wednesday) from Calendar_Day) >= (extract(week(wednesday) from PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','21/10/2020')) - 1)
and extract(week(wednesday) from Calendar_Day) >= (extract(week(wednesday) from PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','21/10/2020') ))
and extract(week(wednesday) from Calendar_Day) <= (extract(week(wednesday) from PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','21/10/2020')) + 1)
```

But this is not working for me.
Need help in resolving this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. `EXTRACT` the week as the code already does. and the year as the weeks repeat every year.
2. `GROUP BY` the week and year.  At this point I find it handy to make a `STRUCT` from the remaining fields as it simplifies the remaining code.
3. make another query that uses the query which did the `GROUP BY`, I used a `WITH`. In this last query, [`LEAD`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lead) and [`LAG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lag) the data with a [`WINDOW`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#navigation_function_concepts) by week.

Here's an example from a public dataset.

```
WITH
  data_by_week AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(year FROM date) AS year,
    EXTRACT(week(wednesday) FROM date) AS week,
    struct( 
      SUM(new_tested) as total_new_tested,
      sum(new_recovered) as total_new_recovered
    ) as week_data
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data`
  GROUP BY
    year,
    week )
SELECT
  year,
  week,
  LAG(week_data) OVER window_by_week AS previous_week,
  week_data AS current_week,
  LEAD(week_data) OVER window_by_week AS following_week
FROM
  data_by_week
WINDOW
  window_by_week AS ( ORDER BY  year, week)
ORDER BY 
  year,
  week
```